# Concat runs twice but if statement only run once and console show going in once only

Tags: reactjs

I have a if else statement that if it is userActionAdded is false, then will run the following case:

```
  case ADD_USER_ACTION:
      console.log('running now!')
      return {
        ...state,
        userActionAdded: true,
        columns: state.columns.concat({title:'action1'}),
      };
```

However, I found that my columns from length of [4] become length of [6] whereby I expect it to be length of[5], I've tried console.log('running now!') on the if-else statement, but it only runs once.

My app.js:

```
{editUserColumns(userActionAdded)}
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data}/>
{console.log(columns)}
```

editUserColumns will be invoked, and on editUserColumns:

My State.js

```
  const editUserColumns = (userActionAdded) => {
    if (userActionAdded) {
    } else {
      console.log("loaded");
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_USER_ACTION,
      });
    }
  };
```

And my reducer

```
    case ADD_USER_ACTION:
      console.log("running now!");
      return {
        ...state,
        userActionAdded: true,
        columns: state.columns.concat({title:'action1'}),
        
      };
```

The State.js console log returns running once only, and reducer also returns running once only, but for the app.js console.log run twice, which is what I expected.

However, the output of app.js console log output array is length of 6 instead of 5

Comment: Absolutely impossible to conclude anything out of this code

Comment: Hi @DmitryReutov, I've edited a bit, is this sufficient? I picked I think what is more important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change a bit your reducer

```
case ADD_USER_ACTION:
  console.log('before we had: ', state.columns.length)
  const newState = {
    ...state,
    userActionAdded: true,
    columns: state.columns.concat({title:'action1'}),
  }
  console.log('now we have: ', newState.columns.length)
  return newDtate
```

to see more clearly what happens or you can put this condition just inside reducer

```
case ADD_USER_ACTION:
  return state.userActionAdded
    ? state
    :  {
      ...state,
      userActionAdded: true,
      columns: state.columns.concat({ title:'action1' }),
    }
```

Update:

Is it inside JSX?

```
{editUserColumns(userActionAdded)}
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data}/>
{console.log(columns)}
```

no, please, do not do like that. Separate functions from JSX, if App.js if functional component then write like this

```
const App = (props) => {
  const { userActionAdded } = props
  useEffect(() => editUserColumns(userActionAdded), [userActionAdded])

  console.log(columns)
  return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
}
```

Then it will work correct and check only if value is changed

Comment: Hey, it works! Thank you, am only seeing one added concat, but why?

Comment: @user5109293123, may be you passed to function variable userActionAdded with value which was out-of-date, i should see all the code to figure it out

Comment: Is wondering ya, will the editUserColumns keep re-rendering on the background as of checking whether the userActionAdded is true? as in, will it slow the overall system as there is an endless checking. The same goes to the state.userActionAdded checking, will it keep re-rendering?